# What is meant by progressive framework?

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js

I have been studying about different frontend frameworks like vuejs, angularjs. most of the time i found this workd "Progressive Framework" on internet. but i am not able to understand it properly.
Vuejs says it can be plugin into simple html project. but same we can do using reactjs as well, using its cdn links.
Than why reactjs is not called "progressive framework"?
Please guide me in that.

Comment: a "progressive framework" is a framework which wants to be a library ))

Comment: sorry, can you please explain it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "progressive framework" is an approach to software framework development that aims for flexibility and gradual adaptation. Progressive frameworks allow developers to use only the parts of the framework they need and extend or customize them as needed. This approach is in contrast to monolithic frameworks, which often provide a large code base and many features, many of which may not be needed.

A good example of a progressive framework is Vue.js. Vue.js allows developers to add features incrementally, from using simple templates and components to integrating routing, state management, and other advanced features.

The advantages of progressive frameworks are:

Flexibility: Developers can choose the parts of the framework that meet their needs instead of incurring unnecessary overhead.

Lightweight: Progressive frameworks tend to use less storage space and resources than monolithic alternatives.

Quick start: They enable a quick start and allow developers to concentrate on the essentials.

Extensibility: As requirements change, developers can extend the framework to meet their new needs.

##### So, why is react not called as such a framework?

ReactJS is not a framework, but “just” a library for handling the user interface. A framework like VUE or Angular has an *all-in-one* basis; an http client, a router, usually a fixed code structure and so on.
In ReactJS you can structure your code however you want. You will need to install third-party routing and HTTP client packages or write your own.
All frameworks (or libraries) can be extended (progressively), but a framework has a lot of extras on board, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks For your Guidence.
But Vuejs being Progressive Framework, Angularjs isnt Progressive Framework.
But still Angularjs also provides same qaualities that vuejs does. so why isnt Angularjs progressive?